# How to store a specific line of a text file in a variable

Tags: string, lua

I am trying to store a specific line from a text file into a variable.

```
file = io.open("words.lua", "r")
randLine = math.random(1, 109583)
local n = 0
for l in io.lines("words.lua") do
  n = n + 1
  if n == randLine then
    word = randLine
  end
end
```

I want to store the string on `randLine` in `word`. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `word = l` instead of `word = randLine`.  Also the first line is not needed as you are not using `file` variable in your code.

Comment: If my answer helped you don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking that green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

lines is an iterator that returns the line, not the line number.

```
file = io.open("words.lua", "r")
randLine = math.random(1, 109583)
local n = 0
for line in file:lines() do
  n = n + 1
  if n == randLine then
    word = line
  end
end
file:close()
```